# %%writefile app.py is not working on vscode. how do i make an app.py file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My mentor using google colab made an app.py file using %%writefile app.py called it a 'magic' command. However, when I tried implementing the same on my vscode file, it didn't work. My mentor used google colab while I use vscode. How do I execute a similar app.py in my vscode environment?

[My mentor's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaS3U.png)

[My failed execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBb2d.png)

(The main ML model is in a different joblib dump, thus it cannot be recreated in an independent system. The image provided aptly represents the problem being encountered. Considering these reasons, code for the same has not been provided here.)

Comment: `%%XXX` commands are Jupyter/IPython magic commands, and only work when run in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can set up a Jupyter Notebook on your own computer (using VScode or otherwise) and then that command will work (although you may find you don't really need it at that point, since you already have a working desktop environment)  Read [more about magic iPython commands here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html).

Comment: what do you mean i might not really need it? can I make an app.py like thing in my own desktop environment?

Comment: If you find that you cannot do something that you believe is what your mentor showed you, why not **ask your mentor** about it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this problem has already been solved and i just edited it to make it more clear on the request of stack overflow. My mentor here was actually an online course teacher who wouldn't take questions if not asked while being taught and all i could do was watch his class recordings. I shortened it all to just mention him as 'mentor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As is shown in your teacher's picture, this is `.ipynb` file which can be run after install ["jupyter"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension on vscode. `%%writefile app.py` is the syntax in jupyter notebook. You can use it to creat files.

So, install the extension and follow your teacher's example. Vscode can do this.

Comment: heya i just went to do exactly what you said and saw that jupyter extension, jupyter keymaps extension and jupyter notebook renderers... all these extensions are already installed. i even installed an independent jupyter-notebook-vscode extension and it still showing the same result as in the picture before. what do I do?

Comment: Creat a `.ipynb` file. For example, `d4.ipynb`.

Comment: i was making another mistake if renaming the same python file as .ipynb from .py and it was giving me the error unknown token % in JSON at position 0. idk what that is but then I realised you said to 'create' a new .ipynb file and not rename. so thanks now it works